# Explicit Representations of Meromorphic Functions as Quotients of Entire Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Any meromorphic function can be expressed as a quotient of two entire functions. However many times meromorphic functions are not given as a quotient. Is there a general algorithm or method, given a meromorphic function (i.e. you know all the poles and their orders), to express it as a quotient of entire functions?

How does one even do it for the Weierstrass $\mathfrak{p}$ function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the method given in the proof of the Weierstrass Factorization theorem to construct a function $g$ with zeros at the poles of your function $f$. Then your desired quotient is $\displaystyle \frac{fg}{g}$.

Comment: I guess this is probably the best you're going to get in general. The expression of the entire functions as infinite products doesn't much help with understanding what they should mean though...